# (Done) Should this question on getting fired on the last day be marked off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request, offtopic

The question [Why did I get fired right before my last day?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/43790/why-did-i-get-fired-right-before-my-last-day) was closed, and I personally do not believe there is any other place on SE to ask this good question. Is it OK to ask where it is closest to being on topic on SE?

This question has three answers from three moderator worthy users, but the users who closed the question not so much. Can we get this question re-opened?

Comment: This is just to address the side-question: "*I personally do not believe there is any other place on SE to ask this good question. Is it OK to ask where it is closest to being on topic on SE?*" **only** if it's on-topic and abiding the site's score/policy. SE *never* promises to be the site where everything is allowed to be asked and answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So why haven't the users who answered reopened the question?

Many times people who answer a question don't track what happens with that question later So perhaps they never noticed that the question was closed.

Or perhaps they just don't care enough to vote to reopen. Many people never cast open or close votes.

Asking for a question to be reopened is one common use of Meta. You could modify this question a bit specifically asking that people vote to reopen the question if you feel strongly about it.

I voted to reopen the question, just to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

> Should this question on getting fired on the last day be marked off topic?

Actually it was marked "primarily opinion-based" because it asked in part for speculation on the state of mind of the employer, which is unknowable.

Also the number of potential answers, as to why someone might be fired on their last day, is infinite.

One hundred users could respond in 100 different ways, and each answer could be equally correct.

The reason questions like this get closed is to prevent the other 97 users from answering.

We (like other SE sites) are looking for questions with a few potential answers that people can agree upon.

If there's a way to rewrite this so it can be answered more objectively, then I think people would be more likely to reopen.

There are some pretty good answers in there already, however.

Comment: Plus, the question and answers are over 2 years old now.